# Adding and using tables to DefaultConnection Database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to add more tables to DefaultConnection database in my MVC project, using code first approach.

I have the following setup:

MyClass.cs

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }
}
```

MyClassController.cs

```
 public class MyClassController : Controller
{
    public MyClassDbContext myClassDbContext = new MyClassDbContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(myClassDbContext.MyClasses.ToList());
    }
}
```

MyClassDbContext.cs

```
public class MyClassDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
}
```

I have not changed `ConnectionString` from its default settings since it is the same database that works with user registration and authentication and I have no issues with it.

After running code I get `A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server...` error on `return View(myClassDbContext.MyClasses.ToList())`.

Question:

Am I missing something basic?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `this.Database.Exists()` line and see if the DB exist there. If the error says "Server not found", you need to configure SQL Server connection string on web.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyClassDbContext: DbContext
{
  public MyClassDbContext(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassController : Controller
{
    public MyClassDbContext myClassDbContext = new MyClassDbContext("Name Of ConnectionString");
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(myClassDbContext.MyClasses.ToList());
    }
}
```

for adding more table you need to use constructor.
above code helps you to make it working.

Comment: This solved my error. I was not calling the `base` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a `model` e.g `MyClass`, you don't need add a new `DBContext` e.g `MyClassDbContext`, you just add `MyClass` to your exist `DBContext` which work for your registration. someting like this:

```
public class OldDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you need add a `Initializer` to auto generatge table(more check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/814618/Use-of-Database-SetInitializer-method-in-Code-Firs)), or you can add table by youself it'll work if table is match to you class.

Answer (score -2):

Please check the connection string in web.config and see if it is valid.Also make sure that the SQL Server is already connected.